# Qt C++ How to play video by android's native player

Tags: java, android, qt, android-intent, video

I want to play a video from my qt widgets application. Since Qt does not support Qmediaplayer in android i cannot use it. Also for some reason the QML videooutput type does not work either.

Therefore, I want to call the native android video player so when a user presses on a button the app chooser launches. I have set up that part.

I have found information from many different places but cant figure out how to put everything together.

The java code which launches the app chooser :

```
   public class videoPlayer extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
    private static videoPlayer instance;

    videoPlayer() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void playVideo(String newVideoPath) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newVideoPath));
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(newVideoPath), "video/*");
        // Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        String title = "play video with";
        // Create intent to show the chooser dialog
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

        // Verify the original intent will resolve to at least one activity
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(chooser);
        }
    }
}
```

The C++ code which should call the above java method

```
 QAndroidJniObject videoUrl = QAndroidJniObject::fromString( "file://path/to/video/1.mp4");
    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("path/to/java/src/videoPlayer",
                                       "playVideo",
                                       "(Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                                       videoUrl.object<jstring>());
```

The above should launch the chooser but in my case, it does... NOTHING, no error, no app chooser, no warning, no video, no nothing.

Therefore, How can i call an app chooser in android from qt c++ and pass the url of the video?

Comment: please create a debug output in your java file in the playVideo function (like `Log.Wtf("HERE");` This will help to find out where the error is

Answer (score 0):

I have had QMediaPlayer working with Qt Widgets.

- There are some things to be aware of qt's multimedia widgets are not supported, but multimedia is (QT += multimedia in .pro file).
- The video is not displayed using a QVideoWidget or QAbstractVideoSurfect, its is drawn straight to the android surface.
- I found some video played and some did not. Thoes that did not, the sound plated, but not no image.
- I found qml worked.

```C++
VideoWidget::VideoWidget()
{
    setPalette(Qt::transparent);
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true );
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, true );
    setAutoFillBackground(false);
    setStyleSheet("QWidget{background-color: transparent;}");
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);

    playlist = new QMediaPlaylist;
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://stage.static.video.sky.com/skymedia/2016/02/116956.ism/manifest-clip-006ifst2.m3u8"));
    playlist->setCurrentIndex(0);

    player = new QMediaPlayer (this, QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback);
    //player->setVideoOutput(this);
    player->setPlaylist(playlist);
}
```

Comment: Since then, I have found that through some video player, a lot did not. If you derive a class from QAbstractVideoSurface, you get passed a series for OpenGL textures.